# How do I create a shopping cart Item in FXML/JavafX?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I've been looking all over the internet and looking for stuff related to this for the past several days, and I was wondering if it is possible to create [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkcyh.png) using Javafx? I've done something like this using Javascript, however the code for that is much different, and very inefficient for the project I'm creating using Javafx.

I am aware of a method using TableView, where I can add to an observable list, from a database, and it can add everything automatically, however, Would it be possible to do something similar using a database, and an observable list add create a "block" with all the information, and keeps adding on?
Would greatly appreciate it if someone could point towards the correct path

Comment: You are looking for [`ListView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html).

Comment: the "right" way is to create user control that represents the particular block. then it is trivial to sort the controls in a list, table, or other container.

Comment: Use a `ListView` with horizontal orientation and a custom cell factory. If the `ListView` scrolling behaviour does not suit your needs you could simply create a custom control for displaying your items and place multiple of them in a `HBox` or something like this...